# Local development, events and ruby on jets

Tags: ruby, aws-lambda, rubyonjets

I'm trying out **ruby on jets** since we'd like to reuse rails code but we are deploying on AWS lately.
We'd like to have a smooth offline development experience such as the one provided by **Serverless**.
Has anyone managed to test events such as **S3** or **SNS** in RubyOnJets without deploying the lambda?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with RybyOnJets but it seems to be using AWS. It might be possible to use localstack:

https://github.com/localstack/localstack

to simulate AWS services on local machine.

Comment: Yep, it uses AWS and it runs Puma in local or API Gateway when you deploy. Unfortunately all other kinds of lambda events (S3, SNS) work only when you deploy (basically because the framework is essentially a CloudFormation client that also act as Rails when you run it locally). Our team is working in order to make it so that it also subscribe to events given you have mock platforms such as Moto o Serverless offline plugins. We are at alpha but it kind of works.

Comment: Localstack does support SNS/S3 and seems to support cloudformation. Maybe there’s a way to pass custom AWS url to localstack when deploying RubyOnJets.

Comment: Localstack runs on docker, which is something we cannot run on some of our develop machines. It's interesting though, I'll keep an eye until the time we might use docker more extensively.

Comment: Docker is optional for localstack. You can run it without it.

Comment: Interesting, I'll check it out then!